# Input number auto change value by stepUp and stepDown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have this input type="number"

```
</div>
  <input id="data-filter" class="form-control form-control" type="number" value="2021"/>
</div>
```

What i need is a script that change the input value using the stepUp and stepDown buttons from "2021" to "2022" and then "2021" again. This because i have a function related to that input and the function doesn't read the default value of element input. It happens only if i fill the input text with "2021" again, or i use the stepUp/stepDown buttons.

**Edit:**

I use that input to perform a search in a table-rows, what i need on the page load is to filter only the rows that contains the year 2021. The function works great, but it doesn't on page load using a default value. So i need to change manualty the input value.

the filter:

```
$('#data-filter').on('load', function () {
    changeFilter.call(this, 'data');
});
```

the function changeFilter:

```
function changeFilter(filterName) {
    filters[filterName] = this.value;
    updateFilters();
}
```

update filters function:

```
function updateFilters() {
    $('.task-list-row').hide().filter(function () {
        var
            dataValue = $(this),
            result = true;

        Object.keys(filters).forEach(function (filter) {

            if (filters[filter] && (filters[filter] != 'Tutti') && !filters[filter].includes('-')) {
                result = result && dataValue.data(filter).toLowerCase().includes(filters[filter].toLowerCase())
            }
            else if (filters[filter] && (filters[filter] != 'Tutti') && filters[filter].includes('-')) {
                result = result && convertDate(filters[filter]) === dataValue.data(filter);
            }
            if (filters[filter] === '') {
                result = true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setUp() {
    let dataValue = document.getElementById('data-filter').value;
    document.getElementById('data-filter').value = ++dataValue;
}

function setDown() {
    let dataValue = document.getElementById('data-filter').value;
    document.getElementById('data-filter').value = --dataValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setUp()
{
    dataValue = document.getElementById('data-filter').value;
    document.getElementById('data-filter').value = ++dataValue;
}

function setDown()
{
    dataValue = document.getElementById('data-filter').value;
    document.getElementById('data-filter').value = --dataValue;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it does change the value of input "number" at the page loading, but it doesn't work with the search filter. I don't know why but it seems to need an manual input. Is any other way to simulate it?

Comment: because i think that you are declaring two times `dataValue` one in the function `updateFilters` and the other one outside

Comment: sure, i declare multiple times **dataValue** in the code. I need to do it to make filters works (i use related filters too).